# Decrease width on Bespoke.js

Tags: javascript, css, bespoke.js

I'd like to know how to decrease the width between `<sections> </sections>` within the 'Classic' theme for Bespoke.js

The GitHub can be found here - http://markdalgleish.com/projects/bespoke.js/

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think all the main framework is predominantly in the link included below, so not neccesarily.  - https://github.com/markdalgleish/bespoke.js/tree/master/demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it from css as long as you're using the default width for a certain box.
CSS:

```
.classic .bespoke-parent section.bespoke-inactive.bespoke-before {
    left: 55%;
}

.classic .bespose-parent section.bespoke-inactive.bespoke-after {
    left: 45%;
}
```

You can play with left values until you get the desired result. At least this is I came up with on a fast Bespoke overview.